# Tensorflow Dataset .map() API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Couple of questions about this

For occasions when I'd like to do something like the following in Tensorflow (assume I'm creating training examples by loading WAV files):

```
import tensorflow as tf 

def _some_audio_preprocessing_func(filename):
   # ... some logic here which mostly uses Tensorflow ops ...
   with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        wav_filename_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [])
        wav_loader = io_ops.read_file(wav_filename_placeholder)
        wav_decoder = contrib_audio.decode_wav(wav_loader, desired_channels=1)
        data = sess.run(
                [wav_decoder],
                feed_dict={wav_filename_placeholder: filename})
        return data

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*.wav')
dataset = dataset.map(_some_preprocessing_func)
```

1. If I have a parse_image() function that uses tensor ops - should
   this be part of the main Graph? Following the example set [in Google's own audio TF tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/input_data.py#L109), it looks like they create a separate graph! Doesn't this ruin the point of using Tensorflow to make things faster?
2. Do I use tf.py_func() any time any single line isn't from the tensorflow library? Again, I wonder what the performance implications are and when I should use this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use [`Dataset.map(map_func)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map), TensorFlow defines a subgraph for all the ops created in the function `map_func`, and arranges to execute it efficiently in the same session as the rest of your graph. There is almost never any need to create a `tf.Graph` or `tf.Session` inside `map_func`: if your parsing function is made up of TensorFlow ops, these ops can be embedded directly in the graph that defines the input pipeline.

The modified version of the code using `tf.data` would look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops as contrib_audio

def _some_audio_preprocessing_func(filename):
    wav_loader = tf.read_file(filename)
    return contrib_audio.decode_wav(wav_loader, desired_channels=1)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*.wav')
dataset = dataset.map(_some_preprocessing_func)
```

If your `map_func` contains non-TensorFlow operations that you want to apply to each element, you should wrap them in a [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) (or [`Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), if the data generation process is defined in Python logic). The main performance implication is that any code running in a `tf.py_func()` is subject to the Global Interpreter Lock, so I would generally recommend trying to find a native TensorFlow implementation for anything that is performance critical.

Comment: Hi. I have a follow up question on this. If I am using this **dataset** to train a model, then after training how do I save it such that the TensorFlow ops from the **_some_audio_preprocessing_func** are also included in the final model?
Thanks